# events created with python vobject are not recognised by ms exchange

Tags: python, exchange-server, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I create an meeting invite using the python vobject and django's `EmailMultiAlternatives` as follows:

```
cal = vobject.iCalendar()
cal.add('method').value = 'REQUEST' #IE/Outlook needs this
vevent = cal.add('vevent')
start = datetime.datetime(start.year, start.month, start.day, start.hour, start.minute, 0, 0, gettz(timezone))
end = datetime.datetime(end.year, end.month, end.day, end.hour, end.minute, 0, 0, gettz(timezone))
vevent.add('dtstamp').value = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
vevent.add('organizer').value = "mailto:" + organizer.email
vevent.add('uid').value = uid
vevent.add('sequence').value = str(sequence_number)
for participant in participants:
    vevent.add('attendee;cutype=individual;role=req-participant;partstat=needs-action;rsvp=true').value = "mailto:" + participant.email
vevent.add('dtstart').value = start
vevent.add('dtend').value = end
vevent.add('summary').value = title
vevent.add('description').value = desc
vevent.add('last-modified').value = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
vevent.add('status').value = 'CONFIRMED'
vevent.add('location').value = ''
vevent.add('priority').value = '5'
vevent.add('class').value = ''
vevent.add('transp').value = 'OPAQUE'
vevent.add('created').value = created
vevent.add('x-microsoft-cdo-busystatus').value = 'BUSY'
vevent.add('x-microsoft-cdo-alldayevent').value = 'FALSE'
vevent.add('x-microsoft-cdo-insttype').value = '0'
vevent.add('x-microsoft-cdo-intendedstatus').value = 'FALSE'
vevent.add('x-microsoft-cdo-importance').value = '1'
vevent.add('x-microsoft-cdo-appt-sequence').value = str(sequence_number)
```

The email sent is as follows:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0735652256227437116=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Test Meeting
From: "..." <...@example.com>
To: ...@example.com
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 13:31:43 -0000
Message-ID: <20110621133143.17903.84489@...>
Reply-To: "..." <...@example.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Jun 2011 13:29:25.0546 (UTC) FILETIME=[3D2A38A0:01CC3017]

--===============0735652256227437116==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="===============1854598015118304554=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============1854598015118304554==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Subject: Test Meeting
Time: 8 p.m. - 9 p.m. GMT+0530 Asia/Kolkata
Moderator: ... (...@example.com)
Message: A test meeting.
--===============1854598015118304554==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

        <table width=3D"100%">
            <tr bgcolor=3D"#d8d8d8">
                <td align=3D"center">
                    <table width=3D"530px" bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" style=3D"ma=
rgin-top:20px;padding:10px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:left;">
                        <tr>
                            <td  style=3D"padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=
">
                                    <font color=3D"#336699" size=3D"14px" =
style=3D"font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Meeting Title:</b></font>
                                    <font size=3D"14px" style=3D"font-size=
:14px;">Test&nbsp;Meeting</font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  style=3D"padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=
">
                                    <font color=3D"#336699" size=3D"14px" =
style=3D"font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Meeting Time:</b></font>

                                    <font size=3D"14px" style=3D"font-size=
:14px;">June 21, 2011</font>
                                    <font size=3D"14px" style=3D"font-size=
:14px;">8 p.m. - 9 p.m.</font>

                                    <font size=3D"11px" style=3D"font-size=
:11px;">GMT+0530 Asia/Kolkata</font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style=3D"padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=
">
                                    <font size=3D"14px" color=3D"#336699" =
style=3D"font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Moderator:</b></font>
                                    <font size=3D"14px" style=3D"font-size=
:14px;">...</font>
                                    <font size=3D"14px" style=3D"font-size=
:14px;">(<a href=3D"mailto:...@example.com">...@example.com</a>)</font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style=3D"padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=
">
                                    <font size=3D"14px" color=3D"#336699" =
style=3D"font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Message/Description:</b></fon=
t><br>
                                    <font size=3D"14px" style=3D"font-size=
:14px;">A&nbsp;test&nbsp;meeting.<br /></font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
--===============1854598015118304554==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; name="invite.ics";
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:IST
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20000101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=3DYEARLY;BYMONTH=3D1
TZNAME:IST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:IoCJJ_840167408_31@example.com
DTSTART;TZID=3DIST:20110621T200000
DTEND;TZID=3DIST:20110621T210000
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=3DINDIVIDUAL;ROLE=3DREQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=3DNEEDS-ACTIO=
N;RSVP
 =3DTRUE:mailto:...@example.com
CLASS:
CREATED:20110621T052344Z
DESCRIPTION:A test meeting.\n
DTSTAMP:20110621T133143Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20110621T133143Z
LOCATION:
ORGANIZER:mailto:...@example.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
--===============1854598015118304554==--
--===============0735652256227437116==
Content-Type: application/ics; name="invite.ics"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invite.ics"

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
--===============0735652256227437116==--
```

Which when decoded looks like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0735652256227437116=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Test Meeting
From: "..." <...@example.com>
To: ...@example.com
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 13:31:43 -0000
Message-ID: <20110621133143.17903.84489@...>
Reply-To: "..." <...@example.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Jun 2011 13:29:25.0546 (UTC) FILETIME=[3D2A38A0:01CC3017]

--===============0735652256227437116==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="===============1854598015118304554=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============1854598015118304554==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Subject: Test Meeting
Time: 8 p.m. - 9 p.m. GMT+0530 Asia/Kolkata
Moderator: ... (...@example.com)
Message: A test meeting.
--===============1854598015118304554==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

        <table width="100%">
            <tr bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
                <td align="center">
                    <table width="530px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin-top:20px;padding:10px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:left;">
                        <tr>
                            <td  style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                                    <font color="#336699" size="14px" style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Meeting Title:</b></font>
                                    <font size="14px" style="font-size:14px;">Test&nbsp;Meeting</font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                                    <font color="#336699" size="14px" style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Meeting Time:</b></font>

                                    <font size="14px" style="font-size:14px;">June 21, 2011</font>
                                    <font size="14px" style="font-size:14px;">8 p.m. - 9 p.m.</font>

                                    <font size="11px" style="font-size:11px;">GMT+0530 Asia/Kolkata</font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                                    <font size="14px" color="#336699" style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Moderator:</b></font>
                                    <font size="14px" style="font-size:14px;">...</font>
                                    <font size="14px" style="font-size:14px;">(<a href="mailto:...@example.com">...@example.com</a>)</font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                                    <font size="14px" color="#336699" style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"><b>Message/Description:</b></font><br>
                                    <font size="14px" style="font-size:14px;">A&nbsp;test&nbsp;meeting.<br /></font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
--===============1854598015118304554==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; name="invite.ics";
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:IST
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20000101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=1
TZNAME:IST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:IoCJJ_840167408_31@example.com
DTSTART;TZID=IST:20110621T200000
DTEND;TZID=IST:20110621T210000
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP
 =TRUE:mailto:...@example.com
CLASS:
CREATED:20110621T052344Z
DESCRIPTION:A test meeting.\n
DTSTAMP:20110621T133143Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20110621T133143Z
LOCATION:
ORGANIZER:mailto:...@example.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
--===============1854598015118304554==--
--===============0735652256227437116==
Content-Type: application/ics; name="invite.ics"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invite.ics"

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:IST
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20000101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=1
TZNAME:IST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:IoCJJ_840167408_31@example.com
DTSTART;TZID=IST:20110621T200000
DTEND;TZID=IST:20110621T210000
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP
 =TRUE:mailto:...@example.com
CLASS:
CREATED:20110621T052344Z
DESCRIPTION:A test meeting.\n
DTSTAMP:20110621T133143Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20110621T133143Z
LOCATION:
ORGANIZER:mailto:...@example.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
--===============0735652256227437116==--
```

This email works in every environment like Thunderbird/Lightening, Outlook (without Exchange backend), GMail Calender, etc. except when the calendering is handled by Exchange.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange strips out the content of the email when an application/ics attachment is included. If that alternate view is removed, then the problem should clear itself up.

Answer (score 0):

if you still have the problem, you could have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648531/1167333.

one possible issue I encountered is that for some minor syntax detail, outlook was refusing to  display the invitation.
To test if your icalendar file is  valid you can try running it through an online validator:

- http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/
- http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/