# How to allow gmail to recoginze ics attachments

Tags: php, email, calendar, gmail, icalendar

I'm trying to attach an ics calender event to an email via a PHP script. When the email is received, the attachment is present, but gmail does not provide the "Agenda" preview or "add to calendar" link.

The Content-Type is text/calendar and the event looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//Foo//Bar//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:This is the summary
ORGANIZER;CN=Common Name:MAILTO:email@example.com
LOCATION:Place
UID:5025023356309823
DTSTART:20141110T100000Z
DTEND:20141110T140000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I've seen, and tried, several suggestions to modify various fields in the invite without making any progress. I know the event is valid, however, because when I manually attach it to an email (sent from gmail) the event details and calendar link are present in the email.

Does anyone know what's necessary for gmail to recognize the invite and display the event details in the body of the email?

Comment: Have you read: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6047

Answer (score 1):

Also note that the ORGANIZER in ics and recipient name cannot be same, if same then loading of calender invite fails.

eg -> You want to send invite to `xyz@mail.com`
and in ics

```
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:xyz@mail.com
```

then the ics will not load the calender invite in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to attach the icalendar in the email as a mime multipart as documented in RFC6047.

Though not in php, a working python example is available at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648531/1167333

see [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047#section-4.5)