# Cannot see event title in the email invitation on Microsoft Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, mime-types, icalendar, amazon-ses

The event invitation sent by my python code to Microsoft Outlook does not show the event heading and description.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sender = PersonInfo("MY NAME", "ID@gmail.com")
    rec1= PersonInfo("MY NAME", "ID@outlook.com")
    rec2= PersonInfo("NAME", "ID2gmail.com")
    recipients = [rec1, rec2]
    subject = "Hi"
    body = "How is everything?"


    dtstart = datetime(2020, 9, 3, 22, 15, 0)
    dtend = datetime(2020, 9, 3, 22, 30, 0)

    ics = build_cal_event("ImpEvent", "Greeting", sender, recipients, dtstart, dtend) #Creates ICS file

    with open("event.ics", 'w') as f:
        f.write(ics)
        
    SendCalendarInvite(sender, recipients, subject, body, ics)
```

The function `build_cal_event` is as follows (omitted some of the code for brevity):

```
def build_cal_event(event_name, event_description, \
                  organizer, attendees,\
                  dtstart, dtend):
    # cal = icalendar.Calendar()
    str_list = []
    str_list.append('''\
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
..........
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
'''.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")))

    
    cal = ''.join(str_list)
    return cal
```

It generates the following ICS file (replaced IDs and names to preserve confidentiality):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:myOrgName
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=ID:mailto:ID@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=ID:
 mailto:ID@outlook.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=ID:
 mailto:ID@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:impevent
UID:81d19fd7-833d-4d56-8d2d-1a343dee77b1
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:ImpEvent
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20200903T221500
DTEND;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20200903T223000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20200903T215335Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2118692743
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGEXTERNALLINK:
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGCONFLINK:
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The `SendCalendarInvite` function is as follows:

```
def SendCalendarInvite(sender, recipients, subject, body, ics=None):
    aws_region = "us-east-1"
    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=aws_region)
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = sender.email
    msg["To"] = ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.email, recipients))
    msg["Content-class"] = "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage"

    ics_name = "{}.ics".format(subject.replace(" ", "_").upper())


    part_email = MIMEText(body,"html")
    part_cal = MIMEText(ics,'calendar;method=REQUEST')

    msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg.attach(msgAlternative)
    

    ics_name = "{}.ics".format(subject.replace(" ", "_").upper())
    ical_atch = MIMEBase('text', 'calendar', **{'method' : 'REQUEST', 'name' : ics_name})    
    ical_atch.set_payload(ics)
    ical_atch.set_type('text/calendar; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST; component = VEVENT')
    encoders.encode_base64(ical_atch)
    ical_atch.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
    ical_atch.add_header('charset', 'UTF-8')
    ical_atch.add_header('component', 'VEVENT')
    ical_atch.add_header('method', 'REQUEST')
    ical_atch.add_header('Content-class', 'urn:content-classes:calendarmessage')
    ical_atch.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename={}".format(ics_name))
    ical_atch.add_header('Content-ID', 'calendar_message')
    ical_atch.add_header('Content Description', ics_name)
    ical_atch.add_header("Filename", ics_name)
    ical_atch.add_header("Path", ics_name)

    eml_atch = MIMEText('', 'plain')
    encoders.encode_base64(eml_atch)
    eml_atch.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "")
    msgAlternative.attach(part_email)
    msgAlternative.attach(part_cal)
    
    try:
        result = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=msg['From'],
            Destinations=[recipient.email for recipient in recipients],
            RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()}
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
        print(result['MessageId'])
```

The gmail recipient sees the invitation in this way:

[image]

It looks okay.

However, the event invitation for the Outlook recipient looks like this:

[image]

**The event name and event description are missing in the invitation received by Outlook. How can I ensure that Outlook correctly processes the event invitation sent by my code and shows the event name and description?**

**EDIT 1:**

The mime email looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1597738219983052864=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Hi
From: ID@gmail.com
To: ID@outlook.com, ID@gmail.com
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage

--===============1597738219983052864==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============6779992366809651548=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============6779992366809651548==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

How is everything?
--===============6779992366809651548==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:OrgName
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=MYNAME:mailto:ID@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=MYNAME:
 mailto:MYNAME@outlook.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=NAME:
 mailto:ID@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:impevent
UID:f250a41d-84c0-4f12-be83-38d2d51f5586
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:ImpEvent
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20200903T221500
DTEND;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20200903T223000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20200904T122939Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2118692743
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGEXTERNALLINK:
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGCONFLINK:
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

--===============6779992366809651548==--

--===============1597738219983052864==--
```

**EDIT 2:**

My concern is why is the event name not being detected when the mime email contains it: `DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:impevent`

Comment: did you solve this? I am facing the same problem =(

Comment: @GuilhermeSimãoCouto Can you assign an empty string to `subject` and see what output you get?