# Why encode_base64 give me TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, smtplib

I have an error, TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not NoneType.
The error raised from: encoders.encode_base64(eml_atch) line 56.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders
import os,datetime

CRLF = "\r\n"
login = "my@email.com"
password = "mypassword"
attendees = ["attendees1@gmail.com", "attendees2@gmail.com","attendees3@gmail.com"]
organizer = "ORGANIZER;CN=organiser:mailto:first"+CRLF+" @ada-asia.com"
fro = "Fahim Maula <fahim.maula@ada-asia.com>"

ddtstart = datetime.datetime.now()
dtoff = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
dur = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
ddtstart = ddtstart +dtoff
dtend = ddtstart + dur
dtstamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
dtstart = ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
dtend = dtend.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")

description = "DESCRIPTION: test invitation from pyICSParser"+CRLF
attendee = ""
for att in attendees:
    attendee += "ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE"+CRLF+" ;CN="+att+";X-NUM-GUESTS=0:"+CRLF+" mailto:"+att+CRLF
ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR"+CRLF+"PRODID:pyICSParser"+CRLF+"VERSION:2.0"+CRLF+"CALSCALE:GREGORIAN"+CRLF
ical+="METHOD:REQUEST"+CRLF+"BEGIN:VEVENT"+CRLF+"DTSTART:"+dtstart+CRLF+"DTEND:"+dtend+CRLF+"DTSTAMP:"+dtstamp+CRLF+organizer+CRLF
ical+= "UID:FIXMEUID"+dtstamp+CRLF
ical+= attendee+"CREATED:"+dtstamp+CRLF+description+"LAST-MODIFIED:"+dtstamp+CRLF+"LOCATION:"+CRLF+"SEQUENCE:0"+CRLF+"STATUS:CONFIRMED"+CRLF
ical+= "SUMMARY:test "+ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%d @ %H:%M")+CRLF+"TRANSP:OPAQUE"+CRLF+"END:VEVENT"+CRLF+"END:VCALENDAR"+CRLF

eml_body = "Email body visible in the invite of outlook and outlook.com but not google calendar"
eml_body_bin = "This is the email body in binary - two steps"
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Reply-To']=fro
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = "pyICSParser invite"+dtstart
msg['From'] = fro
msg['To'] = ",".join(attendees)

part_email = MIMEText(eml_body,"html")
part_cal = MIMEText(ical,'calendar;method=REQUEST')

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msgAlternative)

ical_atch = MIMEBase('application/ics',' ;name="%s"'%("invite.ics"))
ical_atch.set_payload(ical)
encoders.encode_base64(ical_atch)
ical_atch.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'%("invite.ics"))

eml_atch = MIMEBase('text/plain','')
encoders.encode_base64(eml_atch)
eml_atch.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "")

msgAlternative.attach(part_email)
msgAlternative.attach(part_cal)

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(login, password)
mailServer.sendmail(fro, attendees, msg.as_string())
mailServer.close()
```

Actually, I got this script from [Sending Meeting Invitations With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823574/sending-meeting-invitations-with-python), and I don't know how it works. I want to test it first but I got this error. How to fix this?

Comment: and what decision is?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like this is Python2 code and things changed a bit for Python3.

The issue is this line:

```
eml_atch = MIMEBase('text/plain','')
```

Change the line to this and it will work:

```
eml_atch = MIMEText('', 'plain')
```

It should effectively do the same thing as the original line. Also change the imports to this:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders
import os,datetime
COMMASPACE = ', '
```